# HAVING COUNT in cql Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I've created a query for PostgreSQL that I must also adapt to cassandra. 
The query is:

```
SELECT s.rsid FROM locus l, snp s WHERE l.snp_id = s.id GROUP BY s.rsid HAVING (count (s.rsid)>10) ORDER BY s.rsid;
```

In cassandra I have a single table with all files. I tried to use this query in Cassandra but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT rsid FROM keyspace_snp.snp GROUP BY rsid HAVING (count (rsid)>10) ORDER BY rsid;
```

I think that in cql does not exist having count. How can I count lines that have at least 10 rsid equal?
Can you help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the postgresql is an RDBMS but C* is a NoSQL.
those are very different from both!
for this reason, you must change the data model of data saved in postgresql and migrate them to new data model based on NoSQL and C* data model to get a query on them.
another perspective you should look for this, it that cqlsh does not have `HAVING` key to getting a query on this.